# ThreeTenABP not parsing date

Tags: android, date, datetime, timezone

I am trying to convert ISO 8601 time into something human readable and in the local timezone of the Android device.

```
String date = "2016-09-24T06:24:01Z";
LocalDate test = LocalDate.parse(date, ISO_INSTANT);
```

But it returns:

> method threw 'org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeParseException' exception

From reading http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT it seems like what I'm doing should be possible.

What am I doing wrong?

### Edit

Expanded exception error:

> Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: DateTimeBuilder[fields={MilliOfSecond=0, NanoOfSecond=0, InstantSeconds=1474698241, MicroOfSecond=0}, ISO, null, null, null], type org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeBuilder

### Edit 2

The solution is in the answer below. For anyone that stumbles across this, if you want to specify a custom output format you can use:

```
String format = "MMMM dd, yyyy \'at\' HH:mm a";
String dateString = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format).withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(instant);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@alex answer is correct. Here is a working example.

Instant represents a point in time. To convert to any other local types you will need timezone.

```
String date = "2016-09-24T06:24:01Z";
```

This date string is parsed using the DateTimeFormatter#ISO_INSTANT internally.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse(date);
```

From here you can convert to other local types just using timezone ( defaulting to system time zone )

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
LocalDate localDate = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
LocalTime localTime = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalTime();
```

Alternatively, you can use static method to get to local date time and then to local date and time.

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault());
LocalDate localDate = localDateTime.toLocalDate();
LocalTime localTime = localDateTime.toLocalTime();
```

Comment: I hope a thousand people up-vote your answer Reddy. That worked perfectly. The ThreeTen documentation is quite poor in my opinion, so your answer above is the best resource that can be found for parsing timezoned date strings. Thanks very much

Comment: What if I want to change from java.util.Date to iso String ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `Instant.parse()`.

This will give you an `Instant` that you can combine with a time zone to create a `LocalDate`.

Comment: Will that work with an existing timestamp? ie. `2016-09-24T06:24:01Z`

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin:

Converts to LocalDateTime directly based on your local time zone::

```
val instant: Instant = Instant.parse("2020-04-21T02:22:04Z")
val localDateTime = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime()
```

Converts to Date and time separately based on your local time zone:

```
val localDate: LocalDate = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate()
val localTime: LocalTime = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalTime()
```